# getting a list of passengers and putting them in seats. ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

So i've been at this for 4 hours and i'm totally stumped.

Create a simple Passenger class that records a passenger’s name and seating preference. Write a program that repeatedly requests the name of a passenger (sentinel loop), then the user’s seating preference. The preference will consist of a row number and seat letter (assume 21 rows and seats A, B, C and D). Search an ArrayList of Passenger objects for a matching name. If it is already in the list, set its new seating preference; otherwise, create a new Passenger and add it to the end of the list. here is the UML https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ir7sQ.jpg

and here is the code i have so far. I cannot get my do while loop right. And i'm not sure what my next step would be here.

```
public class Passenger{

private String name;
private int row;
private int seat;


public  Passenger(){

}


public Passenger(String passengerName, int requestedRow, int requestedSeat){

    name = passengerName;
    row = requestedRow;
    seat = requestedSeat;


    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("enter the passenger name or 'stop' to quite: ");
name = sc.next();

    do{
     System.out.println("what row would you like to sit on? ");
     row = sc.nextInt();
     System.out.println("what sear would you like to sit on? ");
     seat = sc.nextInt();
     }while(name == "stop");
}

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public int getRow(){
        return row;
    }
    public int getSeatNumber(){
        return seat;
    }
    public char getSeatCode(){
        return seatPreference();
    }


public  char seatPreference(){
    char newSeat = 0;
    if(seat == 1){
        newSeat = 'A';
    }
    else if(seat == 2){
        newSeat = 'B';
    }
    else if(seat == 3){
        newSeat = 'C';
    }
    else if(seat == 4){
        newSeat = 'D';
    }
    return newSeat;
    }

public void setPreference(int newRow, char newSeat){

}
```

}

Comment: `while(name == "stop")`. Don't use `==` to compare content of Strings. `Use equals()`.

Comment: also, should have a ! so its `while(!name.equals("stop"));` Otherwise it only works if everyone's name is stop

Answer (score 1):

In OOP you can't use == to compare strings because you would only check the memory reference of the string.. I would use String.Compare(string1, string2). It returns 0 if equals or -1 or 1 if it doesn't.

I would also use loop like this

```
while(String.Comapre(name.ToUpper(), "Q") != 0)
{

}
```

Also, unless required, I would use List<> Dictionary<> or DictionaryList<> instead of ArrayList.

Comment: Minor typo: "String.Compare" instead of "String.Comapre"

Answer (score 0):

To compare `String`s use the `equals` method.

```
do{
     System.out.println("what row would you like to sit on? ");
     row = sc.nextInt();
     System.out.println("what sear would you like to sit on? ");
     seat = sc.nextInt();
while(name.equals("stop"));
```

Comment: simple as that. Thank you sir

Answer (score 0):

The Java language specification says it all

> While == may be used to compare references of type String, such an
>   equality test determines whether or not the two operands refer to the
>   same String object. The result is false if the operands are distinct
>   String objects, even if they contain the same sequence of characters.
>   The contents of two strings s and t can be tested for equality by the
>   method invocation s.equals(t)